# Flash Drive Overheating

Tags: usb-drive, overheating, heat

I recently purchased a Samsung 32GB USB 3.0 flash drive. It works great in all my machines/OSes. While it's plugged into my System76 Gazelle Pro running Xubuntu, the flash drive gets very hot. Even if I leave the flash drive plugged in and unmount it from the system, it still heats up. Any idea on how to resolve this? I like this flash drive and don't want to chance loosing data due to this.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue. Try contacting System76.

Comment: Just checking: Is the Samsung 32GB USB 3.0 flash drive running cooler in other computers?

Comment: Is it that drive the only one that gets hot in that same port? You should test others as part of a normal troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution, with the last OS install, I didn't include the System76 PPA that contains the hardware drivers. Appears to be fine now.